# How do I blit an image with transparency over another image in Metal?

Tags: ios, image, metal, metalkit

Whenever I try to blit an image that has transparent parts in Metal, the transparent parts are replaced with black.

To be clear, my images do not contain any semi-transparent pixels. They're  either solid color or completely transparent.

I have a simple ViewController that sets up Metal and tries to blit 2 images. But the transparent parts of the second image are black and don't reveal the first image below.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    id <MTLDevice> device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice();
    self.commandQueue = [device newCommandQueue];
    MTKTextureLoader *textureLoader = [[MTKTextureLoader alloc] initWithDevice:device];
    self.texture = [textureLoader newTextureWithCGImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"].CGImage options:nil error:nil];
    self.texture2 = [textureLoader newTextureWithCGImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"].CGImage options:nil error:nil];

    self.metalView = [[MTKView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100) device:device];
    self.metalView.framebufferOnly = NO;
    self.metalView.delegate = self;
    self.metalView.colorPixelFormat = MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm_sRGB;
    [self.view addSubview:self.metalView];
}

- (void)drawInMTKView:(MTKView *)view
{
    id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [self.commandQueue commandBuffer];
    id<MTLBlitCommandEncoder> blitEncoder = [commandBuffer blitCommandEncoder];

    [blitEncoder copyFromTexture:self.texture sourceSlice:0 sourceLevel:0 sourceOrigin:MTLOriginMake(0, 0, 0) sourceSize:MTLSizeMake(self.texture.width, self.texture.height, self.texture.depth) toTexture:self.metalView.currentDrawable.texture destinationSlice:0 destinationLevel:0 destinationOrigin:MTLOriginMake(0, 0, 0)];
    [blitEncoder copyFromTexture:self.texture2 sourceSlice:0 sourceLevel:0 sourceOrigin:MTLOriginMake(0, 0, 0) sourceSize:MTLSizeMake(self.texture2.width, self.texture2.height, self.texture2.depth) toTexture:self.metalView.currentDrawable.texture destinationSlice:0 destinationLevel:0 destinationOrigin:MTLOriginMake(20, 20, 0)];
    [blitEncoder endEncoding];

    [commandBuffer presentDrawable:self.metalView.currentDrawable];
    [commandBuffer commit];
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Blitting, by definition, replaces the entire destination region. If you want to exclude the transparent pixels of the second texture, you'll need to render it with alpha blending (or alpha test via `discard_fragment`) or a compute shader.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Warren. Btw, love your metal tutorials, they've been invaluable when trying to learn Metal. I have since set up a metal scene with a simple quad which displays an image via a shader and was able to make several of them display at once thanks to your instancing tutorial. When doing it that way, I was able to set blending options on the pipeline and now the transparency works as expected. Do you think this is a sufficiently fast approach, or would bitting with a discard_fragment shader be more performant?

Comment: I think blending is the better choice here, even in the binary (alpha = 0 or alpha = 1) case.